# new macro for \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP

Tags: mathtools

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\pr{\mathbb{P}}

\makeatletter
\let\Pr\undefined
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\@Pr[1]{\pr}[]{}{#1}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\@@Pr[2]{\pr_{#1}}[]{}{#2}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\@@@Pr[3]{\pr_{#1}^{#2}}[]{}{#3}
\def\@@@@Pr#1{\@ifnextchar^{\expandafter\@@@Pr\@gobble}\@@Pr#1}
\def\Pr{\@ifnextchar_{\expandafter\@@@@Pr\@gobble}\@Pr}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    $\Pr_{1}^{2}{A}$
\end{document}
```

I am defining a macro for probability environment as above, and I want the equation in the document to be equivalent to

```
$\mathbb{P}_1^2[A]$
```

I cannot understand why the above code is not working. It seems like `\@ifnextchar^` is false in the above.

Comment: This should be possible to do via some `xparse` construction. I can also mention my own package, `semantex`, which is kinda like “`\DeclarePairedDelimiter` on steroids” and can be used to create interfaces for constructions like the one you want, but with a different interface.

Comment: @Gaussler it is _very_ easy to do with `xparse`, just don't try to do everything via `\DeclarePaired...`, it's better to split it up.

Comment: @daleif I know perfectly well that it is very easy with `xparse`, thank you. `:-)` If you doubt my knowledge of the powers of that package, I invite you to take a look at the source code of `semantex`. However, I dislike your implementation since the order of the arguments `\Pr^{...}_{...}[<size>]` feels unnatural to me; I prefer `\Pr[<size>]^{...}_{...}`.

Comment: @Gaussler OPs choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a lot easier to just use `xparse` for the `\Pr` part and `\DeclarePairedDelimier` for the brackets:

The `e` type for grabbing the `_` and `^` is super useful.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% load this if you use an old latex, new latex has xparse in the kernel
%\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Brackets[]
\RenewDocumentCommand\Pr{ e{_^} }{
  \mathbb{P}
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{\sb{#1}}% do if not empty
  \IfNoValueF{#2}{\sp{#2}}% do if not empty
  \Brackets
}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  \Pr_{1}^{2}*{\frac12}
  \\
  \Pr{A}
  \\
  \Pr_2{Y}
  \\
  \Pr^3_2{Y}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\RenewDocumentCommand` is better instead of the clumsy `\let\Pr\undefined`

Comment: @egreg correct, changed